# has_many multiple foreign key search

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
User
 #

Cars
 belongs_to :father, :class_name => "User"
 belongs_to :user

user = User.find(1)
```

Guys help I can get the user's cars by typing `user.cars` (searches cars using `user_id`) but how exactly can I get it to search using father_id?

Obviously I can do a `Car.find_by_creator_id(...)` but I wanted to know if there was a railish solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up the other side of the relations and specify `:inverse_of` for each in the `User` model. Something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :father_cars, :class_name => "Car", :inverse_of => :father
  has_many :cars, :inverse_of => :user

  # ...
end

Cars < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :father, :class_name => "User", :inverse_of => :father_cars
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :cars

  # ...
end
```

You can then access the `:father` relation with

```
u = User.find(1)
cars = user.father_cars
```